# android : why the memory size is not decreasing even after finishing the sub activity?

Tags: android, memory-management

Why the memory size is not decreasing even after finishing the sub activity?

I have two activities : first_activity and second_activity

There is a button in first_activity.

Memory usage is : 3 MB

```
    int usedMemory= (int)(Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() / 1048576L);
```

When I click on this button it will start the second activity.

```
Intent intent   = new Intent(getBaseContext(),second_activity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Till now the memory usage is : 3 MB

In the second activity, I am displaying 8 images through a ViewFlipper.

Then the memory usage increased to 17 MB.
On the back key pressed, I am finishing the second_activity.

```
      @Override
     public void onBackPressed()
     {
         setResult(1);
         finish();
         System.gc();
         super.onBackPressed();
     }
```

When I am coming back from the second_activity to first_activity, its memory usage is again showing as 17 MB. Why it is not freeing up the memory of second_activity?

And if i try to navigate to second_activity again , the application is force closing due to OutOfMemoryError.

I don't know whether my question is foolish one, But I am facing this problem and I can't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with how Java and the Android OS are handling memory. Unlike C (and similar class dev languages) the Java language (and Android OS that rely on it) do their own garbage disposal.

I wouldn't depend on it in the code, as it's very complex (and still decided by the OS)

You can read more here http://chaoticjava.com/posts/how-does-garbage-collection-work/

Answer (score 0):

GC cannot be forcefully called. You should recycle your view in order to release memory.